# List the groups using django-auth-ldap

Tags: django, django-models, ldap, django-admin, django-auth-ldap

I'm trying to retrieve a list of groups from LDAP using django-auth-ldap. It is already authenticating against the LDAP but now I need to retrieve the groups available so I can use them in one of my Models.

One of my models has a group attr that will map to LDAP groups, I want to retrieve those groups to populate a combo so the user can pick one.